# Do I need to update my GSS code in Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

I just read that Memgraph has released something called [Orb](https://memgraph.com/blog/how-we-integrated-custom-css-like-language-to-style-graphs). I don't quite understand does this mean that I should update my existing GSS code or is everything the same for me?

Do I need to update Memgraph Platform or download a new version of Memgraph Lab? I'm running Memgraph 2.3.1 and Memgraph Lab 2.2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Orb](https://github.com/memgraph/orb) is a graph visualization library that was created for Lab v2.0.0. The visualization engine is **open-source now**.

There are **no changes to GSS** so everything stays the same, no changes are needed. In the referenced article you can read about how GSS works with Orb on the architecture level.

For future updates of GSS, you can always check [GSS Reference guide](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph-lab/style-script/reference-guide).